# Set the text in ImageButton

Tags: android, imagebutton

I have a ImageButton which looks like this.

```
 <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ImageButton"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginBottom="6px"
            android:layout_marginRight="3px"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Logo"
            android:background="@drawable/button_bg_purple"
            android:scaleType="fitStart"
            android:src="@drawable/ImageButton" />


 ImageButton ImgButton= (ImageButton) this.findViewById(R.id.ImageButton);
```

Now I need to add a dynamic text in ImageButton programmatically and I cannot use button.
How can I do it?

Thanks In Advance ...

Comment: Why can't you use a Button? ImageButtons don't have a text property. They extend ImageView. If you don't want to use a Button, then use a TextView. OR... you'll have to draw your text inside the ImageButton PROGRAMMATICALLY... such an overkill!

Comment: ImageButton can not have text!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`ImageButton` cannot contain text:

Options you can try

1) use `Button` instead of `ImageButton`

2) use `ImageButton` and `TextView` below to show text

Hope this could help

Answer (score 5):

You cannot set text to ImageButton because it has no method as setText() or android:text property.

ImageButtons can't have text (or, at least,  `android:text` isn't listed in its [attributes](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageButton.html)). It looks like you need to use Button (and look at `drawableTop` or `setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(int,int,int,int))`.

Instead of ImageButton try with Button. You can able to add the button background image.So try with Button instead of ImageButton.

Answer (score 3):

you use of **drawableRight** or **drawableLeft** attribute and use text attribute for create Button with text and image.

```
<Button 
 android:id="@+id/buttonok" 
 android:layout_width="match_parent" 
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:drawableLeft="@drawable/buttonok"
 android:text="OK"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/Button"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginBottom="6px"
    android:layout_marginRight="3px"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Logo"
    android:scaleType="fitStart"
    android:background="@drawable/ImageYouWantToShow" />
```

```
Button imgButton= (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.Button)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead of Button

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    >
    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/prevButton"
        />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:paddingTop="16dp"
            android:paddingBottom="16dp"
            android:paddingLeft="8dp"
            android:paddingRight="8dp"
            android:src="@drawable/arrow_left"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:background="#00000000"
            android:enabled="false"
            android:clickable="false"
            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="prev"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:background="#00000000"
            android:textColor="#FF000000"
            android:enabled="false"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            />

    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```