# Android Imagebutton with text

Tags: android

I am making an application for android that has some buttons like the picture I attached, these buttons are a ImageButton with GradientDrawable (`button.setBackgroundDrawable (gd);`) to the picture frame and `button.setImageBitmap (bp);` which is the image to start the application fee and finally got a b`utton.setBackgroundColor (Color.TRANSPARENT);` for the background color.

Link image:

[image]

My question is, is there any way for me to stay button in the same way as in the attached picture but with a text on the button? Is that the ImageButton has no option to add text and should use simple Button but does not support this button to put these four characteristics and stay as in the photo. In the end what I try to achieve is a button closest thing to the photo I attached but with a text in the middle.

Deputy code I use to put the image and design of the button.

```
final ImageButton button = new ImageButton(this);
button.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
button.setImageBitmap(bp);

button.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
button.setId(contador);
button.setBackgroundDrawable(gd);
```

Comment: You can probably use a TestView and set the image and text both.

Comment: Where does `HTML`, `CSS`, `IOS` or `jQuery` come into this question?

Comment: did you try --button.setText("myText")---

Comment: The image button dont accept this setText, is only to image

Comment: use TextView with compound drawables

Comment: Im trying now this way Napolean

Answer (score 0):

ImageButton don't support text adding, instead you can use Button and set its Background with an image and text.

take a look at this topic : [Set the text in ImageButton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21776676/set-the-text-in-imagebutton)

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I put a TextView with setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds property and a drawable on top and the text on the bot