# text not showing in ImageButton with icon or image

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imagebutton

I need some help please I cannot show the text under or below on my icon or image in `ImageButton` I tried to use the `TextView` but it messes my button I don't have idea how to show the text. here is my xml.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical">


    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:background="#eeeeee" android:layout_marginTop="30dp">

        <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:padding="30dp"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:background="@drawable/button1_style"
                android:src="@drawable/icon1_48dp"
                style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored" />

       <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:padding="30dp"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
                android:background="@drawable/button2_style"
                android:src="@drawable/icon2_48dp"
                android:tint="#ffffff"

                />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:background="#eeeeee" android:layout_marginBottom="20dp">

    <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:padding="30dp"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
                android:src="@drawable/icon3_48dp"
                android:background="@drawable/button3_style"
                android:tint="#ffffff"
              />

        <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:padding="30dp"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
                android:src="@drawable/icon4_48dp"
                android:background="@drawable/button4_style"
               />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: text cannot show in ``ImageButton`` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21776676/set-the-text-in-imagebutton

Comment: how to apply the TextView?

Comment: you want the button is a ``ImageButton`` or only ``Button``?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you can use `TextView` for your idea:

Example for button1:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/button1_style"
    android:drawableTop="@drawable/icon1_48dp"
    android:text = "Button1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Add `padding`, `margin`, `drawablePadding` for it if you need.

Comment: I will put the textview after the tag of ImageButton ?

Comment: No, You dont use ImageButton. TextView will replace ImageButton.

Comment: how can I make icon bigger like this size http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40235609/gridview-with-button-and-text

Comment: you can resize your image or use code: Drawable icon = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon1_48dp);
icon.setBounds(0, 0, width, height);
myView.setCompoundDrawables(0,icon, 0, 0);

Comment: Im still new on android can you please tell me where to put or how to implement that code...thank you in advance

Comment: The code added after you flatern layout, it same with android:drawableTop="@drawable/icon1_48dp" in xml but you will resize drawable to put on top of TextView.

Comment: @phongvan...I don't understand what you mean. is drawablePadding can resize ?

Comment: no, drawablePadding make an space between picture and text. You will resize picture at `setBounds` function or use image editor (photoshop ...) to resize the image

Comment: i think use ``android:drawableTop`` in ``Button`` is correct, then use ``drawablePadding`` to change position

Comment: @jemz ``drawablePadding`` for change drawable position, or you use java to change drawable size? not in xml

Comment: @phongvan, in myView.setCompoundDrawables. what is myView ? is that the TextView id ?

Comment: that is your TextView

Comment: phongvan I have problem ,the getDrawable is deprecated..  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.mylayout);

        TextView txambulance = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mytextview);
        Drawable icon = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.buttonstyle);
        icon.setBounds(0, 0, 50, 50);
        txambulance.setCompoundDrawables(0,0, 0, 0);


    }

Comment: also the setCompoundDrawables is cannot be applied to textview

Comment: sorry, the function with no value is null not 0.

Answer (score 1):

Folllowing is the code for 4 images and 4 text below them

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:background="#eeeeee" android:layout_marginTop="30dp">

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:padding="30dp"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:background="@drawable/button1_style"
            android:src="@drawable/icon1_48dp"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored" />


        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:padding="30dp"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
            android:background="@drawable/button2_style"
            android:src="@drawable/icon2_48dp"
            android:tint="#ffffff"

            />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/TextViewlayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="2"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:text="Something 1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <TextView
            android:text="Something 2"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:background="#eeeeee" >

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:padding="30dp"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
            android:src="@drawable/icon3_48dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button3_style"
            android:tint="#ffffff"
            />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:padding="30dp"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
            android:src="@drawable/icon4_48dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button4_style"
            />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/TextViewlayout2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="2"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:text="Something 3"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <TextView
            android:text="Something 4"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: the text is outside in button